# Regex that matchs two seperate text that also ignores everything in between

Tags: regex, regex-group, cisco

I'm your typical networking guy and I'm totally new to this type of stuff. I'll do my best to explain what it is I need help with.

I'm using Cisco Prime to find all devices that contain two separate strings.

The first is-

```
device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME
```

The second is-

```
ip address-helper 1.1.1.1
```

Here's the last thing I tried.

```
(device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME)|(ip address-helper 1.1.1.1)
```

Ideally I'd like to match the first string, ignore any white space and any characters in between and then match the second string.

I've ran it through Regex101 and it seems to work but it just seems like there's a better if not cleaner way. From what I've read so far the pipe character matches one thing or something else. I need it to match both so I can tell Cisco Prime to raise a violation and make a fix.

Edit: Added sample configs.

```
device-sensor filter-list cdp list CDP_LIST_NAME
*device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME*
device-sensor filter-list lldp list LLDP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor filter-spec dhcp include list DHCP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor filter-spec lldp include list LLDP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor filter-spec cdp include list CDP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor accounting
device-sensor notify all-changes
!
!
interface Vlan1
 description PRINTERs
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.10.10.1
 ip helper-address 10.10.10.2
 ip helper-address 1.1.1.1
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
```

Comment: Welcome @BearManPig. It would be helpful if you could format the question to show an example of the strings that need to be searched and then what you wish to match.

Comment: I've added the sample config. Basically I'd like to match device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME and ignore any white space/characters than match ip address-helper 1.1.1.1.

Comment: So given the string of text above, you want to know if it it contains: `device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME` and `ip address-helper 1.1.1.1`? Or do you want to extract those two values to form a new string?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to know if the text contains device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME and ip address-helper 1.1.1.1.

Comment: If you are looking for fixed strings, you don't really need to use regular expressions for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
/(device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME).*(ip helper-address 1\.1\.1\.1)/igm
```

This will match the first term, then any characters till the next term. We need to escape the . in the ip address. As the pattern has the terms in brackets, two capture groups will be created. These are actually not needed, but included to demo you can return the matched groups.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/CB1Xet/1)

Snippet below:

```js
const data = 'device-sensor filter-list cdp list CDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-list lldp list LLDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-spec dhcp include list DHCP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-spec lldp include list LLDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-spec cdp include list CDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor accounting device-sensor notify all-changes ! ! interface Vlan1 description PRINTERs ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0 ip helper-address 10.10.10.1 ip helper-address 10.10.10.2 ip helper-address 1.1.1.1 no ip redirects no ip unreachables';

let match = /(device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME).*(ip helper-address 1\.1\.1\.1)/igm.test(data);

console.log(match);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot!

Comment: `.` will not match the newline character so if your text is split across lines, which I believe it it is is in reality and not as in this code snippet, this regex will not match unless you use the the `s` ("dotall") flag.

Comment: Yes, it's across multiple lines.

Comment: Then it needs to be `let match = /(device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME).*(ip helper-address 1\.1\.1\.1)/igs.test(data);`.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson JS doesn't have a `s` modifier, but if the string has multiple lines then it would be a `m` Thanks

Comment: @Chev See https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction. I just tested this with `node`. Multiline mode or the `m` flag is something else altogether. It allows `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of lines and not just the beginning and end of the input string.

Comment: I see, never used it before as the majority of references only define i m & g. Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions for searching for fixed length strings may be a bit of overkill, so this I think is the better, cleaner way.

This is JavaScript, but most languages allow you to search for a substring within another string and return the index of where it found the match or some error indication if the substring was not found:

```js
const text = 'device-sensor filter-list cdp list CDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME\ndevice-sensor filter-list lldp list LLDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-spec dhcp include list DHCP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-spec lldp include list LLDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor filter-spec cdp include list CDP_LIST_NAME device-sensor accounting device-sensor notify all-changes ! ! interface Vlan1 description PRINTERs ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0 ip helper-address 10.10.10.1 ip helper-address 10.10.10.2 ip helper-address 1.1.1.1 no ip redirects no ip unreachables';

if (text.indexOf('device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME') != -1 &&
    text.indexOf('ip helper-address 1.1.1.1') != -1) {
    console.log('Found it')
}
```

In Python:

```
text = """device-sensor filter-list cdp list CDP_LIST_NAME
*device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME*
device-sensor filter-list lldp list LLDP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor filter-spec dhcp include list DHCP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor filter-spec lldp include list LLDP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor filter-spec cdp include list CDP_LIST_NAME
device-sensor accounting
device-sensor notify all-changes
!
!
interface Vlan1
 description PRINTERs
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.10.10.1
 ip helper-address 10.10.10.2
 ip helper-address 1.1.1.1
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables"""

if ('device-sensor filter-list dhcp list DHCP_LIST_NAME' in text
    and 'ip helper-address 1.1.1.1' in text):
    print('Found it')
```